# setup pycharm IDE for Qgis plugin Development by integratin SNAP "sentinel application platform"

Tags: python, plugins, qgis, snap

Am using pycharm as IDE,Qgis"3.30" integrated python"3.9" and snap "Sentinel Application platform" software which provides a python package.

d:

- setup snap with 3.9 python , i got this error:

  ```
  > snappy-conf C:\Users\utente\anaconda3\envs\snap2\python.exe C:\Users\utente\anaconda3\envs\snap2\Lib
  i trie

  The launcher has determined that the parent process has a console and will reuse it for its own console output.
  Closing the console will result in termination of the running program.
  Use '--console suppress' to suppress console output.
  Use '--console new' to create a separate console window.
  Configuring SNAP-Python interface...
  java.io.IOException: Python configuration failed.
  Command [C:\Users\utente\anaconda3\envs\snap2\python.exe .\snappyutil.py --snap_home "C:\Program Files\snap" --java_module C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\SNAP\modules\org-esa-snap-snap-python.jar --force --log_file .\snappyutil.log --jvm_max_mem 11G --java_home "C:\Program Files\snap\jre\jre" --req_arch amd64]
  failed with return code 10.
  Please check the log file 'C:\Users\utente\anaconda3\envs\snap2\Lib\snappy\snappyutil.log'.
          at org.esa.snap.python.PyBridge.configureJpy(PyBridge.java:232)
          at org.esa.snap.python.PyBridge.installPythonModule(PyBridge.java:149)
          at org.esa.snap.rcp.cli.SnapArgsProcessor.processPython(SnapArgsProcessor.java:103)
          at org.esa.snap.rcp.cli.SnapArgsProcessor.process(SnapArgsProcessor.java:49)
          at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:202)
          at org.netbeans.spi.sendopts.Option$1.process(Option.java:387)
          at org.netbeans.api.sendopts.CommandLine.process(CommandLine.java:317)
          at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.HandlerImpl.execute(HandlerImpl.java:62)
          at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.Handler.cli(Handler.java:69)
          at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.notifyHandlers(CLIHandler.java:234)
          at org.netbeans.core.startup.CLICoreBridge.cli(CLICoreBridge.java:82)
          at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.notifyHandlers(CLIHandler.java:234)
          at org.netbeans.CLIHandler$1.exec(CLIHandler.java:268)
          at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.finishInitialization(CLIHandler.java:447)
          at org.netbeans.MainImpl.finishInitialization(MainImpl.java:256)
          at org.netbeans.Main.finishInitialization(Main.java:92)
          at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:316)
          at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Python configuration error: Python configuration failed.
  Command [C:\Users\utente\anaconda3\envs\snap2\python.exe .\snappyutil.py --snap_home "C:\Program Files\snap" --java_module C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\SNAP\modules\org-esa-snap-snap-python.jar --force --log_file .\snappyutil.log --jvm_max_mem 11G --java_home "C:\Program Files\snap\jre\jre" --req_arch amd64]
  failed with return code 10.
  Please check the log file 'C:\Users\utente\anaconda3\envs\snap2\Lib\snappy\snappyutil.log'.
  ```
- setup qgis version that's compatible with snap in term of python requirements. and i got this error:

  ```
  pycharm error while configure python interpreter : Cannot set up a python SDK at Python 3.12 (try03) (4) (C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.0\apps\Python36\python.exe). The SDK seems invalid
  ```

***Am trying to develop a qgis plugin by integrating some Snap functionalities.***

-------------------------

***Thanks for your time***

--------------------------